# Insert number of textboxes relating to number of rows in a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a staff rota system in visual studio and would like to populate some textboxes with the staff names from a database to ensure the user does not miss any staff for the rota. Obviously staff will come and go therefore the number of textboxes may need to change.

For instance one week there may be 5 staff members to enter into the rota, but if a staff member leaves the company then the number of textboxes will have to automatically change and be populated with the names from the table after the staff member is deleted from the database.

For the end result I plan on having a list of textboxes populated with the names of existing staff members from the table. This will then allow the user to select their shift times and lunch hours etc.

Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough information to give a helpful answer.  Are staff members stored in a table?  What technology do you use to query your tables?  Are you using ASP.NET webforms or MVC?  Etc.

Comment: google "repeater asp.net". that should get you started

Comment: Yes I have a staff table where I wish to extract their names into textboxes (as mentioned in the first paragraph). And I am using asp.net (as displayed in the tag for this question).

Comment: Why do you insist on using TextBox? Do you plan to edit these names or do you just show them? In the latter case use a Listbox, ListView, Grid not a variable number of textboxes

Comment: @Steve I just wish to show them so I guess labels would work or another tool which would prevent editing. The user must be able to select a staff member's working hours next their name which will then be entered into the database to match their staffID. Therefore I would require separate fields in order to input back into my relational database. It is the whole dynamic aspect of this task which I am struggling with as taxtboxes (or labels) will need to be identified in order to input back into the database. Not to mention how I have only been learning c# for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thousand Thanks for the suggestion of using asp.net repeater control.

I did not wish to edit the information I was extracting so I have created a template which extracts the data into labels. Thank you and apologies as this question is in the negative.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of textboxes...

Use Radio buttons if ONLY one can be selected from the list

Use Checkboxes if MORE than one can be selected from the list

Only use a textbox if you wish to EDIT the names (data)